# How to rename property created by Object.defineProperty with GCC

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I wish to rename object property in ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS mode.

Code before optimization:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function Container() {
  var items = [];
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'items', {
    set: function(value) {
      items = value;
    },
    get: function() {
      return items;
    }
  });
}

var container = new Container();
container.items = [1,2,3];
console.log(container.items);
```

After optimization:

```
var b = new function() {
  var a = [];
  Object.defineProperty(this, "items", {set:function(c) {
    a = c
  }, get:function() {
    return a
  }})
};
b.e = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(b.e);
```

Closure Compiler not renamed the property name - "items".

Comment: Why do you want to rename it?

Comment: I don't think any compiler would ever rename any object-property on it's own. It's to dangerous to do it automatically.

Comment: I'm shocked: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#propnames My conclusions: don't ever use ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS with gcc. I'd use some foreign minifyer like uglifyjs

Comment: @Oriol, it would better hide the code, new name will be less noticeable. Please compare - `b.e = [1, 2, 3];` and `b.items = [1, 2, 3];` I can add that property name in to externs.js ￼
but this is not what is expected.

Comment: @thomas Property renaming is one of the biggest advantages of Closure-compiler but it does require code written in a compatible manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @owler correctly answered, Closure-compiler can not rename `Object.defineProperty` created properties because they are always quoted. Instead, use `Object.defineProperties` as they may be either quoted or unquoted.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function Container() {
  var items = [];

  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    items$: {
      set: function(value) {
        items = value;
      },
      get: function() {
        return items;
      }
    }
  });
}

var container = new Container();
container.items$ = [1,2,3];
console.log(container.items$);
```

*Note: Properties defined via Object.defineProperties are not eligible for type-based renaming and as such will only be renamed if the property is not defined on any type in the externs set. As such, my example replaces the `items` property with `items$`.*

Answer (score 2):

Closure Compiler will not rename properties that are ever referenced with a quoted string:

> Whenever possible, use dot-syntax property names rather than quoted strings. Use quoted string property names only when you don't want Closure Compiler to rename a property at all.

See https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#enable-ui

Since `Object.defineProperty` requires a string for the property name I'm guessing there is no way to get Closure Compiler to rename it.  If you really need this, you could ask on the [Closure Compiler Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/closure-compiler-discuss) if there is some way to trick the compiler into doing that.