# ES5 getters and setters are "potentially surprising and difficult to reason about"

Tags: javascript, properties, setter, getter

I quote the recent [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-classes-getters-and-setters):

> Do not use [JavaScript getter and setter properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). They are potentially surprising and difficult to reason about, and have limited support in the compiler. Provide ordinary methods instead.
>
> **Exception:** when working with data binding frameworks (such as Angular and Polymer), getters and setters may be used sparingly. Note, however, that compiler support is limited. When they are used, they must be defined either with `get foo()` and `set foo(value)` in the class or object literal, or if that is not possible, with `Object.defineProperties`. Do not use `Object.defineProperty`, which interferes with property renaming. Getters must not change observable state.
>
> Illegal:
>
> ```
> class Foo {
>   get next() { return this.nextId++; }
> }
> ```

It is an opinion of Google but I would like to truly understand the reasons.

First, I think the *"compilers"* that have a limited support are Babel / Traceur / TypeScript? Or is there a lack of support in some ES5 engines?

Additionally, I would like to understand what are the *"surprising and difficult"* reasons for which the author thought. I see these limitations:

1. `Object.assign()` doesn't copy the getters, but execute them and copy the values;
2. With the `get name()` syntax, it's not possible to add a getter to an existing object. With an existing object, the `Object.defineProperty` must be used.
3. It's not possible to define a getter with a lambda, this limitation can lead us to use the old school `let that = this` in some case.

I don't understand the statement: *"`Object.defineProperty` interferes with property renaming*". (What is a "property renaming"?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would presume what they meant is:

> "[potentially] surprising":

Properties with getters and setters do not necessarily act like normal properties. Therefore, they violate the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Suppose you had a property that returned 0 if the value assigned to it was a negative number:

```
myObj.prop = -7;
expect(myObj.prop).to.equal(-7);  // fails
```

> "[potentially] difficult to reason about":

For similar reasons. Properties with getters and setters don't necessarily act like like normal properties which means you can't necessarily reason about them the same way you would reason about normal properties.

Suppose we had the above property again. You could not do the following:

```
myObj.prop = -7;

console.log(myObj.prop * 9);

// use substitution to figure out the result of the above statement:

console.log(-7 * 9);   // substitute -7 for myObj.prop
console.log(-63);      // wrong - the above actually logs 0
```

Regarding property renaming: according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366072/how-to-rename-property-created-by-object-defineproperty-with-gcc), the optimizer in the Closure compiler attempts to rename (minify) property names, but it will do so in an incomplete way by renaming the references to them, but not updating the `.defineProperty()` call. Using `.defineProperties()` allows the optimizer to rename the properties correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand the "property renaming" now. About the "potentially surprising": I thinks it's just when the implementation is suprising? The setter in your example should throw an exception for negative numbers and the surprise will vanish. I personally use getters without setters in order to lazily evaluate members and to make read-only (but living) properties. However your answer seems to be a good explanation to the recommendation from Google. I wait a little then I'll validate it.